# Postgres - Select specific rows for each ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following scheme:

```
id | name | price | site_id | agency

1 | NAME | PRICE | 1 | AGENCY1
2 | NAME | PRICE | 1 | AGENCY1
3 | NAME | PRICE | 1 | AGENCY2
4 | NAME | PRICE | 1 | AGENCY2
5 | NAME | PRICE | 2 | AGENCY1
6 | NAME | PRICE | 2 | AGENCY1
7 | NAME | PRICE | 2 | AGENCY1
```

I want to get the first row with a unique agency for each site_id.

For example, the query result for the above scheme is expected to be:

```
1 | NAME | PRICE | 1 | AGENCY1
3 | NAME | PRICE | 1 | AGENCY2
5 | NAME | PRICE | 2 | AGENCY1
```

I have tried to look for solutions with DISTINCT but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you should use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (site_id, agency) t.*
from t
order by site_id, agency, id;
```

Not only is this the most concise method, but it usually has the best performance of possible methods.  You want an index on `(site_id, agency, id)` for optimal performance.

Answer (score 1):

With [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) window function:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.price, t.site_id, t.agency
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by site_id, agency order by id) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3HJpv1AJD2LtRGiMLtNd8A/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name | price | site_id | agency  |
| --- | ---- | ----- | ------- | ------- |
| 1   | NAME | PRICE | 1       | AGENCY1 |
| 3   | NAME | PRICE | 1       | AGENCY2 |
| 5   | NAME | PRICE | 2       | AGENCY1 |
```